# How to select a drop down menu option in Puppeteer bot?

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to customise a Puppeteer bot which fills out a reservation form, searches for an available date and if it’s not available it refreshes the page. The bot only selects some options but I’d like to add more. Currently it leaves the default “1” room in the drop down menu but I’d like to select “2”.
Below is the current code and I’d like to select 2 for no_of_rooms

```
async function prepareAndCheckPage(){
    //select 2 rooms
    await page.select('#form_no_of_rooms', '2'); //this code doesn't work
    //accessibility requirement – this code correctly selects the second radio button
    await page.waitForSelector('#form_rooms_0_accessibilityRequirement_1');
    const accessibilityRequirement = false; 
    page.$eval('#form_rooms_0_accessibilityRequirement_' + (accessibilityRequirement ? 0 : 1), elem => {
        elem.checked = true;
    });
```

Here is the HTML from the page

```
  <div id="accommodation-add-rooms">
    <div class="row / mb-6">
      <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="form-group mb-0"><label class="required" for="form_no_of_rooms">Preferred number of rooms*</label><div id="form_no_of_rooms_help" class="d-block / mb-1">Please note your preferred number of rooms and room configuration are not guaranteed.</div><select id="form_no_of_rooms" name="form[no_of_rooms]" class="col-12  col-md-2 form-control" aria-describedby="form_no_of_rooms_help"><option value="1">
    1
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </option><option value="2">
    2
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </option></select>
```

Obviously I'm very inexperienced in this. What am I doing wrong? I’ve tried both form_no_of_rooms and no_of_rooms

Comment: Welcome to SO! Adding a link to the live page helps immensely in making it possible for folks to help. Usually there is JS involved beyond the static HTML (if not, it's worth mentioning that). Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks, I'll do that on my next post. I've just figured out that my code worked but something else was wrong. I'll probably have a new question very soon though.

Comment: Why not [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68300536/edit) this one to include the relevant info? If you figured it out, please add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help future visitors with the same problem as you.